# SQL Agent job to select a value from table and pass the values as input parameter to execute stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-agent

I have a stored procedure which expects integer as input parameter.
i need this sp to run every 10 mins. for this im thinking to use sql server agent job.

i want to select a set of values from table.column and pass this as an input parameter to the stored procedure every 10 minutes.

Appreciate your assistance in advance.

Thanks & Regards,
Sanjai

Comment: What I try to avoid is writing too much actual queries inside your SQL Server Agent job. Normally I would encapsulate this stored procedure in another one which will handle the fetching & passing of those parameters. Then you'd only have to call a stored procedure in your SQL Server job. Much cleaner, in my eyes.

Comment: Hi Jens, could you guide me to pass select of  table.column values as input parameter to the sub sp. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understand your requirement.

Use `Cursor` (if the set of values are not huge) to pass the values from set of values of table.

```
DECLARE @value VARCHAR(50) -- table.column value

DECLARE myCursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT ColVal FROM Table -- Get the values from table

OPEN myCursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @value   

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
       EXEC dbo.getValue @value  -- Execute the SP
       FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @value   
END   

CLOSE myCursor   
DEALLOCATE myCursor
```

Use this T-SQL in agent job step.

Comment: Hi Pinwar13, i followed the same you have suggested. and the job is completing successfully. but the data which the sp should insert using the input parameter from the cursor is not happening.

Comment: without looking your SP it is hard to say why insert not happening.

Comment: Hi Pinwar13, when i execute the cursor you have given manually in ssms im getting my required data pushed into the table. but this is not happening from sql server agent job when it runs automatically.

Comment: Can you test it by creating an another SP by placing all your code of cursor and call the new SP from Agent. Before running in agent test the SP in ssms. also check you are selecting correct database from the T-SQL option of sql agent.

Comment: It worked. i had not linked the corrct database in sql agent job.